# Items from an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code where I get the data from a json file an put it in an array. I want to take from my array only 5 items, but I want to do that code in the app.js file, not in html file.
So I don't want to use ng-repeat with limitTo.

```
$http.get('auto_quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
        $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
        $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
        shuffleArray($scope.myQuestions);

    });
```

and this is the html

```
    <div id="myQuiz" ng-controller="QuizController">
<p class="txt">{{totalQuestions}}</p>
</div>
```

Someone please tell me how to print in the view only 5 items.

Comment: Are you using ng-repeat to show the questions?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to use the filter limitTo. I want the code to be in the js file, that brings only 5 items, not in the html file.

Comment: @dragon You can also use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to copy a subsection of an array.

Comment: I am new to angular Mike. Please can you show me my code modified with slice?

Comment: It's not Angular, it's just JS. Look at the examples on the page I linked to.

Comment: I used this in my code `$scope.myQuestions = quizData.data.slice(0, 5);` and I get  the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`

Comment: Very strange only on google chrome I get that error. In other browsers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I gest that this is what you are look for,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myQuestions | limitTo: 5">
    <p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

in angular you can use the limitTo filter to customize the number of items to show
Hope this help?

Comment: my friend  I don't want to use the filter limitTo. I want the code to be in the js file, that brings only 5 items, not in the html file.